# Show that an algebra is in $\mathcal{M} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}, \forall E \subset \mathbb{R}, \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c) \} $

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that:
$$ \mathcal{M} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}, \forall E \subset \mathbb{R}, \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c) \} $$
$\mu^*$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Show that $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}$.

I previously had shown that if $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A})$ then $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}, \mu(A)= \mu^*(A)$.

Now in order to show that $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}$ I have to show that if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $\forall E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A^c \cap E).$

I tried to to do it by double inequality. It is true that $E \subset E \cap A \cup E \cap A^c$ thus $\mu^*(E) \leq \mu^*(E\cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c)$, but I am unable to show the inequality the other way.

Comment: Some info about $\mathcal A$ is needed. If e.g. $\mathcal A=\wp(\mathbb R)$ then $\mathcal A$ is an algebra, but not with $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal M$.